# How to convert an integer to byte string in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

In Python, you can convert an integer to 32 bytes big endian like this:

```
num.to_bytes(32, 'big')
```

```
# example
>>> (100).to_bytes(32, 'big')
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00d'
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes

How can I achieve this in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def to_bytestring( num_chars=nil )
  unless num_chars
    bits_needed = Math.log( self ) / Math::LOG2
    num_chars = ( bits_needed / 8.0 ).ceil
  end
  if pack_code = { 1=>‘C’, 2=>‘S’, 4=>‘L’ }[ num_chars ]
    [ self ].pack( pack_code )
  else
    (0…(num_chars)).map{ |i|
      (( self >> i*8 ) & 0xFF ).chr
    }.join
  end
end
```

You also might like to check this link  https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/integer-to-byte-string-speed-improvements/67110